# Detection of a known Object (By Template)

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv, aforge

I need help with Object detection.
I habe to detect position of a Fork and a Knife on a Plate. The Plate is on a Tray.
The Objects are always the same but the Positions can vary.

I'm wokring with c# and [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) + [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Can someone help me with this?

Here is a sample pic: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The brightness and color or the knife/fork-pixels are mostly determined by reflection, so I don't think classic template matching would work with this picture.

The knife has almost no corners, so I'm not sure if an interest point-based algorithm like SIFT would work here.

I think the best approach here could be to use an edge detector (Laplace, Sobel, Canny), trace the lines and perform geometric template-matching the way they did it back in the 1980's.

Here's a very good reference for this approach: [Object Recognition by Computer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262571889)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.
Unfortunatly i don't have the time to read thru a book.

Today i played around with Image Processing Lab (AForge) and i came to to this result:
http://img828.imageshack.us/i/image1er.jpg/

But i realy don't know how i can trace these lines.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: I got a prety good result now but i still don't know how to track these lines:
http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/9763/image1171.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would go for template matching methods which are looking image gradients. Those approaches are robust to changing lighting conditions.

You can take a look at the fast template matching algorithm implemented in:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

Samples included.

The implemented template matching algorithm is based on orientation of gradients, which are very resilient to changing lighting condition. In order to detect your object, a template must be made (e.g. in Paint) and then rescaled.